# Earliest reference of any astrologer (jyotisi) in Rig Veda

Tags: rig-veda, astrology

Jyotis shastra i.e. astrology is one of ancient science of Hinduism, believed to be started right from Rig Vedic period that developed into a vast body of knowledge by many ancient astrologers.

My question here is whether Rig Veda mentions name of any astrologer of that period ?

Comment: Rishi Dirghatamas is his mantra Rig Veda 1.164.11 is talking about zodiac wheel , so we can say that he is a  astrologer of Rig. Vedic  times. - http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v2.132 AND http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01164.htm

Comment: If you want i can write an answer quoting mantras from Rig-Veda of Dirghatamas proving his connection with astrology .

Comment: @SwiftPushkar it's your choice. As per my question  Dirghatamas himself to be an astrologer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Rishi Dirghatamas can be considered as one of the vedic astrologer .

According to  vedic scholar [**David Frawley**](https://www.vedanet.com/vedic-origins-of-the-zodiac-the-hymns-of-dirghatamas-in-the-rig-veda/)  in  the Rig Veda,  there are clear references to a chakra or wheel of 360 spokes placed in the sky. The number 360 and its related numbers like 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 108, 432 and 720 occur commonly in Vedic symbolism. We find clear reference of zodiac in  the hymns of Rishi Dirghatamas (RV I.140 – 164) . Much of this hymn can be understood as a description of the zodiac. It begins: the hymns of Dirghatamas speak clearly of a zodiac of 360 degrees, divided in various ways, including by three, six and twelve, as well as related numbers of five and seven.

Dirghatamas is one of the most famous Rig Vedic Rishis. He was the reputed purohit or chief priest of King Bharata (Aitareya Brahmana VIII.23), one of the earliest kings of the land, from which India as Bharata (the traditional name of the country) was named. Dirghatamas was one of the Angirasa Rishis, the oldest of the Rishi families, and regarded as brother to the Rishi Bharadvaja, who is the seer of the sixth book of the Rig Veda. Dirghatamas is also the chief predecessor of the Gotama family.

---

Here are the mantras from [**Rig-Veda 1.164 .**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v2.132) And here is [**English**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01164.htm) translation

> द्वादशारं नहि तज्जराय वर्वर्ति चक्रं परि दयामृतस्य | 
>  आ पुत्रा
>   अग्ने मिथुनासो अत्र सप्त शतानि विंशतिश्च तस्थुः || 11||
>
> dvādaśāraṃ nahi tajjarāya varvarti cakraṃ pari dyāṃ ṛtasya | 
>  ā
>   putrā aghne mithunāso atra sapta śatāni viṃśatiśca tasthuḥ ||
>
> 11 Formed with twelve spokes, by length of time, unweakened, rolls
>   round the heaven this wheel of during Order. Herein established,
>   joined in pairs together, seven hundred Sons and twenty stand, O Agni.
>
> ---
>
> दवादश प्रधयश्चक्रमेकं त्रिणि नभ्यानि क उ तच्चिकेत | 
>  तस्मिन
>   साकं त्रिशता न शङकवोSर्पिताः षष्टिर्न चलाचलासः ||48||
>
> dvādaśa pradhayaścakramekaṃ trīṇi nabhyāni ka u tacciketa | 
>   tasmin sākaṃ triśatā na śaṅkavo.arpitāḥ ṣaṣṭirna calācalāsaḥ ||48||
>
> 48 Twelve are the fellies, and the wheel is single; three are the
>   naves. What man hath understood it? Therein are set together spokes
>   three hundred and sixty, which in nowise can be loosened.

As the topic of Zodiac is related astrology and  from above conclusion of scholors we can say that Rishi Dirghatamas was a rig-Vedic astrologer .

Comment: a good effort and I voted for it,but not for the right answer. I have great regard for D. Frawley and his work 'Gods,Sages and Kings'.Neither I am not qualified enough to comment on astrological symbolism,but I have doubt on the translation of 'tajjarAya' check it with 'tajjAntir' (RV.4.1.16) I guess it may be a linguistic variation of a place name 'tuje' described at many places in RV. Any way, merely describing astrological symbolism does not make Dirgtamas an astrologer,as writer of a biology book need not to be a biologist.

Comment: Astrology is not there in Vedas. Jyotisha vedanga is astronomy alone. Astrology is a later development